# Не запускается поток java

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Есть класс для потока, код из конструктора касса работает всегда, а run() запускается через раз, в чём может быть причина? В логе пусто.

```
public class SThread extends Thread
    {
        Thread ScoreThread;
        public SThread()
        {
            ScoreThread = new Thread(this);
            ScoreThread.start();
        }
        public void run()
        {
            while(running)
            {
                if(!onDraw)return;
                try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch (InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                score++;
                text = "Score: "+score;
            }
        }
    }
```

Вызываю вот так

```
new SThread();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стартуя поток в конструкторе и передавая `this`, вы передаёте ссылку на объект, который ещё не полностью сконструирован. Поток стартует раньше, чем конструктор завершится, поэтому результат не предсказуем. Плюс в вашем кейсе лучше использовать `Runnable`.

```
public class SThread implements Runnable{
        Thread ScoreThread;
        public SThread(){
            ScoreThread = new Thread(this);
        }
        public void start() {
            ScoreThread.start();
        } 
        public void run(){
            while(running){
                if(!onDraw)return;
                try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch (InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                score++;
                text = "Score: "+score;
            }
        }
    }
```

И запускаем:

```
    SThread thread = new SThread ();
    thread.start();
```